# Why couldn't I use the "Resources.Load" result directly?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The Unity Manual says the `Resources.Load` returns the requested asset as an Object.I wonder why could't I use the returned `Object`directly.For example,I have a Text prefab and I want to add it's instance to the Hierarchy,but the Code below won't work

```
Text prefab;
private void Start()
{
    prefab = Resources.Load<Text>("Prefabs/Text");
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    prefab.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
}
```

I must `Instantiate` the return of the `Resources.Load` first like below

```
Text prefab;
private void Start()
{
    prefab = Resources.Load<Text>("Prefabs/Text");
    GameObject canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
    Text text = Instantiate(prefab);
    text.transform.SetParent(canvas.transform);
}
```

I don't know what's the difference between the `Instantiate` result and `Resources.Load` result,and what the `Instantiate` do ,so that it's return can be added to Hierarchy.

Forgive my poor English!

Comment: You should have a Resource folder in your assets folder as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Method `Instantiate(GameObject)`  you would write a new component, create a new variable of type GameObject, attach the component to an GameObject, and fill the variable in the inspector.

To use the Method `Instantiate(Resource.Load("object path"))` you just need the name/path of the Prefab.

this is extremely useful if you have a huge amount of generated parts in your game (so there are no gameobjects placed in the editor), if you'd want to avoid Resource.Load you'd need some "data-holder-gameobject" placed in an nearly empty scene. edited to make my point a bit clearer

it is aswell helpfull if you have large number of different Prefabs and your method knows the name of the object it wants to build, or you just simply dont want to drag and drop all those prefabs into the inspector window

Resource.Load, loads data from your drive. it's possible that your game is played from a Hard drive, which would mean to load the prefabs the hard drive needs to rotate, position the read-head, and so on.

Instantiate is slow itself even without the need of Resource.Load Instantiate is not that fast. if it happens that you need it very often ( multiple times per second) you should consider some kind of object-pool 1